# Multiple operations over columns and rbind

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the mean, the median and some other stuff using `dplyr`. Since I just read few introductions (most of them rather old), I was wondering whether the following is possible:

```
iris %>% group_by_("Species") %>%
   summarise_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("Sepal")), .funs=perform_some_operation)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Operation
      <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>    <fctr>
1     setosa        5.006       3.428      mean
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770      mean
3  virginica        6.588       2.974      mean
4     setosa          5.0         3.4    median
5 versicolor          5.9         2.8    median
6  virginica          6.5         3.0    median
```

The `Operation`-column is just added for clarity. I do not absolutely need it.

The only thing I could find far was `summarise_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("Sepal")), .funs = c(Mean="mean", Median="median"))`. However this is firstly slow and secondly creates the additional output in columns - not in rows.

EDIT: I do not need the operation which generates the result, to be inside `summarise_at`.

Comment: It is unclear what you want here as I would assume what you said is exactly what you want. What is the point of the operation column? Do you only want a mean or median applied to some portion of each column other than grouping by species? Or do you only want to apply say mean to Sepal.Length and median to Sepal.width?

Comment: As I wrote below the code. The operation column is there to clarify that the first three rows are the means over the species. I want the mean and median applied to all columns with "Sepal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea. The trick is to `gather` and clean the melted colnames, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>% 
 select(starts_with('Sepal')) %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(n1 = mean, n2 = median)) %>% 
 gather(var, val, -Species) %>% 
 mutate(var = gsub('_.*', '', var)) %>% 
 group_by(var) %>% 
 mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
 spread(var, val) %>% 
 arrange(new) %>% 
 select(-new)

#Adding missing grouping variables: `Species` - Innocent warning
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
>      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
>       <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>
> 1     setosa        5.006       3.428
> 2 versicolor        5.936       2.770
> 3  virginica        6.588       2.974
> 4     setosa        5.000       3.400
> 5 versicolor        5.900       2.800
> 6  virginica        6.500       3.000
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution. Generally this seems to be the same as using `summarise_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("Sepal")), .funs = c(n1="mean", n2="median"))`. At least in the third and fourth line.